# Cocos2d use NPOT images (assets)

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am developing a game with the use of Cocos2d and Box2d and I cannot add an image which is not POT (power of two) in size. Do you know how I can deactivate this behaviour ? Thanks.

Edit : cocos2d-iphone 2.1, ObjC, iOS app

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14422637/cocos2d-disabling-only-retina-ipad-graphics

Comment: @ZacharyEspiritu ... the short answer is `no`, this is not a duplicate of the said question.

Comment: obj-c and the app is for iOS

Comment: 2.1 objective-c (iphone)

Comment: Any particular reason you're using such an old version of cocos2d? Isn't it up to v3.x now?

Comment: @JamesWebster : in my case it is about the mandatory 'forklift update' every time the practical jokes department at cocos2d comes up with asinine API semantics changes. I have games in the 400Kslocs own-code where about 20% were affected by the 3.x semantics. Also, 2.2 has much finer (**better**) texture cache capabilities for Just-in time texture loading.

Answer (score 0):

That version supports NPOT images : on startup you should see this :

```
cocos2d: cocos2d-iphone v2.1
cocos2d: compiled with Profiling Support: NO
cocos2d: OS version: 7.1 (0x07010000)
cocos2d: GL_VENDOR:   Apple Computer, Inc.
cocos2d: GL_RENDERER: Apple Software Renderer
cocos2d: GL_VERSION:  OpenGL ES 2.0 APPLE-9.4.3
cocos2d: GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 4096
cocos2d: GL_MAX_TEXTURE_UNITS: 8
cocos2d: GL_MAX_SAMPLES: 4
cocos2d: GL supports PVRTC: YES
cocos2d: GL supports BGRA8888 textures: YES
cocos2d: GL supports NPOT textures: YES
cocos2d: GL supports discard_framebuffer: YES
cocos2d: GL supports shareable VAO: NO
```

make certain you require opengles-2 in your info.plist's `Required device capabilities` clauses.

Answer (score -1):

you can use texturepacker tools to package your image,and if you want to add a image not a pot, you need to show your code ,may be we can find out some wrong

Comment: witch version cocos2dx that you useing?if you use cocos2dx 1.x you need to config in ccConfig.h to support npot ,and if you use cocos2dx 2.x or uper then you need't to config any thing

Comment: this answer should be a comment. The above comment has been answered for in OP's question.